About RMS(Time domain, Frequecy domain)
I have raw data (time data) from 0 to 2.25 seconds. I perform an energy average and carry out an FFT with a frequency resolution of 4 Hz and an overlap of 0. However, the RMS value calculated in the time domain for the entire 0 to 2.25 seconds is slightly different from the RMS value obtained from the FFT results in the frequency domain. Theoretically, these two values should be the same. What could be the reason for this discrepancy? I used a Hanning window and applied energy correction.

By how far are you off? Is your signal reasonably stationary?

Applying a (non-rectangular) window must make the estimate shift-dependent.
So, that explains that: depending on whether samples land in the "roll-off" of your window (in time domain), they contribute more or less to the overall power estimate. Since your samples don't all have the same magnitude, it makes a difference.
To drive this concept home: Imagine you have an all-zeros signal, but there's a single sample in there that has |…|² = 1.
Now, if that sample happens to be in the center of your window $w[n]$ of length $N$, so at index $(N-1)/2$, it will be multiplied with the center of the window, and that will be a relatively large number, here with 1.
Hann window for sample 0…N-1. Source: Olli Niemitalo on wikimedia commons
So, the energy in your output is
$$ E=
 \left\lvert0\right\rvert^2\cdot\left\lvert w[0]\right\rvert^2 + \ldots   + \left\lvert 0\right\rvert^2\cdot\left\lvert w[(N-1)/2-1]\right\rvert^2 + \left\lvert 1\right\rvert ^2\cdot\left\lvert w[(N-1)/2]\right\rvert ^2 +  \left\lvert 0\right\rvert^2\cdot\left\lvert w[(N-1)/2+1]\right\rvert^2 + \ldots,
$$
which is, due to all the $|0|$ factors in there, $E=\left\lvert w[(N-1)/2]\right\rvert^2 = 1$.
Now, do the same, but don't put your 1 it in the middle, but at the very left end, at index $1$. Now the energy is just the magnitude square of the first value in the window. And as you can see in the plot above, that is a very small number! In fact, it's $\left\lvert\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{N}\right)\right\rvert^2$, so for say, $N=1024$, it's roughly $10^{-10}$, so much much much smaller than 1!
So, obviously, your energy correction factor can't be "right" for just any signal. The assumption is that the signal is either constant in envelope, or that we only care about the energy being correct in expectation, not for every realization of the random signal.
If you need to perfectly conserve the energy of your signal, you can't apply a window that changes the energy.

I don’t understand why the window affects the RMS value. Energy correction is applied during the FFT process! Could you explain it in more detail?

The energy correction is only correct if all samples have the same magnitude. I mean, it's just a single number. How could the number "know" whether high-value samples are in the middle of your window, or at the edges?

see my edit. I hope this is fairly understandable.

Isn't "energy correction" the process of adjusting the FFT values so that the energy of the FFT of the signal, after multiplying the Hanning window and the sample, matches the energy of the sample in the time domain? For example, in the case where the "1" is in the center, you apply the Hann window, perform the FFT, and then correct the result so that the energy becomes "1". Similarly, when the "1" is at the far left, you also adjust the FFT result after applying the window so that it matches the energy of "1" in the time domain.

Well, you noticed that you need different factors for different signals, and that the factor you need can only be determined by looking at the signal. But that's not what you're doing: you always multiply with the same factor.
